# Android - SQLitehelper onCreate overwrites copied database

Tags: android

Based on 
[this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) tutorial and the default notepad example by Google, I tried to create my own Database adapter super class.

Now the idea is to copy a pre-created db from my assets folder to my app database folder. I want to use my databasehelper's onCreate method to call the custom method copyDataBase

I don't get any IO errors, but what seems to happen is that the database is created, my custom database is copied over and then overwritten again.

Any ideas why the onCreate method would overwrite my copied database?

Please see my super dbadapter class that contains the custom helper class

```
public abstract class DbAdapter_Super {

    protected static final String TAG = "MyAppDbAdapter";
    protected DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    protected SQLiteDatabase mDb;


    protected static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.android.myapp/databases/";
    protected static final String DB_NAME = "MyAppDB";

    protected static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    protected final Context mCtx;

    protected static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     protected final Context mHelpCtx;          

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {    
            super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
            this.mHelpCtx = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  {

            //Copy pre-created DB
      try{
       copyDataBase();} 
         catch (IOException e) {
          throw new Error("Error copying database");
         }
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){};

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS routes");
            onCreate(db);
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
            //Open your local db as the input stream
         InputStream myInput = mHelpCtx.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

         // Path to the just created empty db
         String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            //if the path doesn't exist first, create it
            File f = new File( DB_PATH );
            if ( !f.exists() )
                f.mkdir();

                //Open the empty db as the output stream
         OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

         //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int length;
         while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
          myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
         }

         //Close the streams
         myOutput.flush();
         myOutput.close();
         myInput.close();     
        }
    }


    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public DbAdapter_Super(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open or create the  database.
     * 
     * @return this
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public DbAdapter_Super open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

}
```

I would really like to keep this abstract super class as is. I just need to understand why the db would be copied over and then overwritten by a blank db. I've tested as much as I can and the db is copied correctly, but overwritten.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `Any ideas why the onCreate method would overwrite my copied database?` - the question isn't why `onCreate()` overwrites the db - `onCreate()` will always overwrite the db.  The question is why is `onCreate()` being called when the database already exists, right?

Comment: It doesn't get called. For testing purposes I just delete it each time so that the onCreate fires and my method to copy the db is called. After that it's never called again when I initiate objects of this class etc. 

My question is still why does my copied database (copied by calling the method from onCreate), get copied, but somewhere, without my knowledge, get overwritten by a default/empty database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well I couldn't force the dbhelper class to work exactely like I wanted. What I instead opted to do was make the `copydatabase()` method public to my dbadapter class. Then I created a checkdatabase method that simple checks if the db already exists.

So the trick was to overrride the dbhelper's onCreate to do nothing. Then, from my dbadapter class I simple checked if the database existed (using the helper's checkdatabase() method) and if it didn't, I just called the copydatase method.

The check method I added to helper class (based on example from link in my first post)

```
public boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
    catch(SQLiteException e){
         //database does't exist yet.
     }

     if(checkDB != null){
         checkDB.close();
     }

     return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

So I then changed the following part my in DBadapter class

```
public DbAdapter_Super open() throws SQLException {
       mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);

       //check if db exisist        
       if (mDbHelper.checkDataBase() != true) 
          try{
              mDbHelper.copyDataBase();

             } 
          catch (IOException e) {
               throw new Error("Error copying database");
           }
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


       return this;
}
```

I'm sure I can still trim and optimize the dbadapter class and do better error handling. But for now, I'm finally able to have a abstract class that I can build table handlers from and it copies my pre-created database.

Thanks to everyone who posted. Dunno why I didn't think of it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

My solution  to this problem is to add an `onOpen()`-procedure :

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        int iversion = db.getVersion();
        if (iversion == 1) {
            onUpgrade(db, 1, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `onUpgrade` does not check for a version and thus always executes the `drop table`.
Try something like:

```
onUpgrade(...) {
  if (newVersion > 1 ) {
    db.execute("drop table .. ");
  }
}
```

Comment: He always sets the database version to 1, so this would make no sense.

Comment: Isn't exactly what you say the reason? :-) onUpgrade() only makes sense to be executed when the new version is >1. But if he does not check, it will always be executed (=callback from system) and thus does the drop table(?)

Comment: its the other way around - `onUpgrade()` is **not** called everytime.  The system checks the version of the database to the version specified in the constructor. If its lower, then `onUpgrade()` is called. If the version is always `1`, there's no reason why the system would call `onUpgrade().`

Answer (score 0):

Every time `DbAdapter_Super.open()` is called a new instance of `DatabaseHelper` is created, which on first use calls it's `onCreate()` method.

To avoid this just crete an instance of `DatabaseHelper` and cache it until closed:

```
public DbAdapter_Super open() throws SQLException {
    if(mDbHelper == null){
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    }
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
    mDbHelper = null;
}
```

or, if you want database to survive application restarts, then just check if database already exists before recreating it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. 

The way I understand it, is that the onCreate is only called once. The SQLiteOpenHelper class checks if the database exists and only if it doesn't exist, does the onCreate method get called. The getWriteableDatabse method basically checks for the existence of the databse.

I did try you solution though and still no joy. 

What's interesting is that if I modify the copyDatabase method to copy to another namespace (for instance testdb) then it works fine. It's as if the onCreate method reserves the MyAppDb namespace and overwrites it somewhere else

Comment: Yes, `onCreate()` is only called once after an instance of `DatabaseHelper` is created. But you are creating a new instance every time `DbAdapter_Super.open()` is called.